# Is this the correct way to init an object that is exposed via a Rest API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The XMl looks like:

```
<blah>
  <prop1>asdf<prop1>
  <prop3>
    <name>name</name>
    <age>age</age>
  </prop3>
</blah>
```

So would creating a new object be like:

```
b = BlahAPI::Blah.new(
      :prop1 => 'abc',
      :prop3 => { 
        :name  => 'name',
        :age   => 11
      }
    )
```

Does that look right?

Comment: API of which service are you connecting to? Public service or just something ActiveResource based? What are you using to parse XML and to build XML objects? Under which circumstances areyou creating a new object? What kind of object? Basically, any information at all.

Answer (score 0):

#### Care for more RDOC anyone?

I'm afraid that the answer to that question is that it depends on how the BlahAPI::Blah object initializer was implemented. An alternative, and perfectly reasonable implementation could be

```
b = BlahAPI::Blah.new('abc, 'name', 11)
```

That's a bit C++'ish but could be what was required. The only way to be sure is to **check the rdoc**

**Aside : External State transfer**

The one thing that you can be sure of is that *if the XML is not providing all of the state required to interact with the service then it isn't a REST interface*. Does that matter? It will if you are trying to create / update resources within the service - unless you have all of the external state, you won't be able to update an existing resource.